# What's the equivalent function of i18n t() function in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, internationalization, i18next

In [i18next](https://www.i18next.com/), people are defining `t()` function as translation utility, vue has vue-i18n, react i18n also has such thing.

Here comes my question, what's the equivalent `t()` function in Laravel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Laravel you  can use `__` helper function for the same.

As per Laravel documentation:

> You may retrieve lines from language files using the `__` helper function. The `__` method accepts the file and key of the translation string as its first argument. For example, let's retrieve the welcome translation string from the `resources/lang/messages.php` language file:

```
echo __('messages.welcome');

echo __('I love programming.');
```

> If you are using the Blade templating engine, you may use the `{{ }}` syntax to echo the translation string or use the `@lang` directive:

```
{{ __('messages.welcome') }}

@lang('messages.welcome')
```

Reference: 
[Laravel -> Localization -> Retrieving Translation Strings](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/localization#retrieving-translation-strings)

Answer (score 0):

`trans('messages.welcome')`, `trans_choice('messages.apples', 10)`, and `@lang('messages.welcome')`

TO display in the blade wrap those in `{{ }}` like `{{ trans('messages.welcome') }}`

To display html contained in them in blade use `{!! !!}` like `{!! trans('messages.welcome') !!}`

https://laravel.com/docs/master/localization

https://laravel.com/docs/master/localization#pluralization

https://laravel.com/docs/master/localization#retrieving-translation-strings